# Java coding style 2019

Tags: java, if-statement, formatting, code-formatting

I am curious to know the current coding style for java. My team is forcing  to use {} for one liner if statements. Although we used to have braces for one liners current java source code does not use braces for one liner if statements anymore and I myself am inclined towards the same.

Python dropped braces altogether.

However I do not see any particular style guide in 2019.. The oracle doc still refers to the 1997 coding style.

What would be correct coding or is it something more to do with developer's preference?

```
   foo();

   if (condition)
      doSomething();

   bar();
```

vs

```
   foo();

   if (condition) {
      doSomething();
   }

   bar();
```

Edit 1:  As Kartik mentioned we can write one liners like this as well:

```
   if (condition) doSomething();
```

For me, it as a developers preference and I am ok with both the approaches but in my current team some developers are of opinion not using braces is a BAD coding practice. I saw the java source code and found in many places braces are omitted. So, I don't believe this to be true. As for google coding style, it was also there for many years and many people continue to use the same. But for new code are there any new guidelines?

Edit 2: This question is marked as opinion based and put on hold

I want to clarify that I am NOT looking for opinions. I am more looking for standard guidelines which Oracle (or java open source communities) might have put forward regarding best practices as of today (2019). Most practices java/google are very old dating back to 1996 and may not be relevant today. Even if there is some reference in some new books and some can share those details it will be very helfpul

Comment: If you are not using braces, make sure you write the whole thing in a single line, like 
`if (condition) doSomething();`

Comment: The personal problem I have with the first style is that it is not so explicit what the closure of the preceding `if` is.  So, I prefer to always using curly braces.  I would be surprised if the official viewpoint would have changed with the latest release of Java (assuming there were one).

Comment: The idea behind always adding braces is that I can add some code without the need to see if I need to add braces.

Comment: I have never seen a coding standard that *doesn’t* require braces for every loop body and if/else body.  The reason behind it is that maintenance developers will add lines while forgetting to add the braces.  This is a real problem that has caused many real bugs.  Also, adding braces costs nothing—it doesn’t hurt readability in the slightest.

Comment: @VGR Then why is the java source code not doing the same?

Comment: For the most part, it does.  Why there are exceptions, I don’t know;  I have never worked at Sun Microsystems.  I do know from experience that every company will cut corners when there are deadlines.

Comment: @VGR That's the reason why I asked this question.. the new code that is written have this style not the old code.. I doubt this will save any time but I feel because java is moving towards a more concise style of coding developers are using this style

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the commonly used style guides for java is the one from Google, see [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

It says:

> Braces are used with if, else, for, do and while statements, even when the body is empty or contains only a single statement.

But the real **general** answer here is: only use such input as *hint* what to do. For you: sit down with your peers, and check out what you like, and then write that down, and go with it. Like: our team decided to use the google style, but to make subtle changes to it here or there.

And then make sure that your tooling supports your preferred style. One of the reasons why we selected "google style" is the fact that you get formatting templates for eclipse, IntelliJ, and even SlickEdit.

I agree that there are no "prominent" style guides for Java8 (and newer) elements, such as lengthy stream statements. That is where "decide with your team what you want" comes in again. We decided for example that

```
stream()
  .filter(...)
  .whatver
```

each go on their own line (one reason for that is the fact that IntelliJ will then give you the return type of each line right there while editing, what I find extremely helpful when working with streams).

Comment: I agree. This style guide is Google's _opinion_; we should make changes as to what suits us the best. I like IntelliJ's four space indents as opposed to Google's two space indents, so I use that.

Comment: @Kartik That is what we did to, go from 2 to 4. Just wondering: do you think something is missing here to get the answer upvote worthy?

Comment: The google guide is also there for many years but the style of writing java code drastically changed after java 8.. people who are following the google code style can continue to do the same but for new code I feel it is more of a preference

Comment: @SubhomoySikdar See my last edit

Answer (score -2):

Write as you like. I prefer brackets.
They help navigate the code.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.